# Finding different type of single quotes in javascript

Tags: javascript, unicode

My requirement: There are three strings with single quotes of different types(like -> '‘’) and when I search with a single quote(i.e -> ') I should get the index of the single quote in all the cases.

e.g:

```
var str1 = "this is someone's question"
var str2 = "this is someone‘s question"
var str3 = "this is someone’s question"
```

`str.indexOf("'");` -> This statement should find single quotes (', ‘ and ’) in all the three variables. Just like the google chrome find works in web page search.
Thanks in advance

Comment: they're different characters. you will need 3 statements or regex

Comment: Google likely either normalizes this, or just searches for the different quotes.

Comment: `.search(/[‘'’]/)`

Answer (score 1):

`var index = /['‘’]/.exec(str3).index`

Answer (score 0):

Using regex & [`.search()`](https://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/jsref_search.asp) you can detect the single-quotes:

---

```js
const regex = /(\'|\‘|\’)/gm;
var str1 = "this is someone's question"
var str2 = "this is someone‘s question"
var str3 = "this is someone’s question"

console.log("Found single-quote @ index: " + str1.search(regex));
console.log("Found single-quote @ index: " + str2.search(regex));
console.log("Found single-quote @ index: " + str3.search(regex));
```